# WPF: Data bindings for visual properties relative to other elements dimensions cause data errors

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I made a converter which calculates simple math expressions from input value.
Here's example use in XAML:

`Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource Expression}, ConverterParameter=x-8}"`

In the designer my `x` is 40. So result is 32: valid. When I run my code however, x is first 0 (error is shown in Output Window, because result is -8, not a valid width). Then of course `x` is 40 again so app works with no visual glitches. Well, not entirely true, because on tablet device just one of instances of controls have totally incorrect size despite other instances have correct size. On my desktop PC layout is always perfect. I don't have a clue how to even start to debug this.

Anyway - why is the pass with `ActualWidth` or `ActualHeight` zero? Are the controls displayed when it happens, but the layout engine doesn't know their actual dimensions yet? And how to deal with it? Ignore the errors, or provide default values for zeroes somehow? Actually my expression calculator understands conditional (ternary) expressions, so I could do that. Is there something in bindings themselves which could delay the binding?

Or maybe - it's an ugly hack which shouldn't be used at all? I'm a little concerned about my app performance on low-end tablets - if it would make too many calculations for layout elements it could become slow.

TBH, the only reason I used this trick I needed percents displayed in a spinner. The size of the spinner is dynamic, depends on the container size. The font of the control could be fixed and the size of the caption set with `ViewBox`. This however gave me very bad looking jumps when the width of the text changed during change of percentage value. So I dropped `ViewBox` and calculated font size with the binding. This led to described errors at runtime. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: As long as your control is not loaded or fully measured, your Actual Size is always 0 (zero). Your converter should made to handle that case too

Comment: @lokusking Oh, I see. The control is not fully measured when it's first rendered. But the data binding occurs so it takes zero and should handle it to return valid output with zero input. Thanks, this explains why the errors occur, now I wonder if `Delay` binding property could avoid it somehow (the zero case).